# Ubuntu Mate disable mousewheel window switch

Tags: shortcut-keys, mate, ubuntu-mate

When cursor is located over the task panel, where the opened windows are listed, turning mousewheel causes active window switch. This is irritating at best.

I want to disable that.
I did find the recomendation to use compiz manager to edit the keybindings https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211863

However, on mate there's different switcher and compiz settings manager shows it as if all the mousewheel bindings were already disabled.

I've tried search functions of both compiz editor and dconf Editor, but nothing comes up on the matter of window switching.

**How do I disable switching windows with mousewheel in the taskbar?**

Actually, I'd be happy if I could disable all possible functions (tab\workspace swith etc.) except for scrolling (it is called scrollwheel for a reason, you know), but I guess that'd be too much to ask.